# Displaying only user specific items from MongoDB collection in Meteor

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I am new to Meteor, and creating a meteor web application for teachers in order for them to keep track of the classes they teach and the students within each class. After logging in, the teacher sees a running list of all of the classes that they personally teach, and will be able to select each individual class in order to view a list of students in that particular class, with options to remove, edit, or add. The teacher will then be able to select an individual student's name, which will take them to a page where the teacher can upload documents (pdfs, word documents, etc) corresponding to the specific student they have chosen. The problem I am running into is how exactly I can display, add, and edit only information that applies to each teacher, since there will be many teachers using the app, each with different classes and students. I have a single collection for both classes and students, but can not seem to wrap my mind around how to only display items that correspond to the presently logged in teacher. What is the best way to go about this?

Answer (score 0):

teacher collection could have an array of classes they teach.

classes collection could have an array of objects. Each object has a teacher and an array of students for that class

Teacher Collection

```
teacher [
classes: {class_id1, class_id2, class_id3}
]
```

Classes Collection

```
classes [
{
 class: history
  {teacher: teacher_id1
   children: { childid1, child_id2, child_id3 }
  }
 {teacher: teacher_id2
  children: { child_id1, child_id2, child_id3 }
 }
},
{
 class:geography {
next iteration
}
```

}
]

You can manage the file uploads by naming the folders uniqueylyy for a teacher class student combination

Answer (score 0):

you said:

> I have a single collection for both classes and students

that sounds like you mean 1 collection total (so far), and not one each for classes and students.

this problem is non-trivial, because you might also want to handle:

1. a teacher teaches a class of a certain subject more than 1x/day
2. more than 1 teacher may teach a subject
3. a semester ends, and there are a whole new group of teacher/class/student relationships

if i were modeling this, i would start with these collections:

1. teachers
2. subjects
3. students

notice i listed "subjects" instead of "classes". classes will come next. a subject might be "History 4", which comes with a textbook and maybe some existing tests and homework assignments, and is offered year after year. or maybe 2 teachers teach History 4 each semester.

each of those collections above represent concepts that are more "durable" than a semester. a teacher has (hopefully) a long career at the school. students may be there 4 years. subjects, though they may evolve over time, stay relatively constant.

the next step is to start making associations among all those collections. here's where "classes" comes into play. to avoid reserved words, let's call it a "schoolClass".

a schoolClass is when the school offers a subject to students w/ a fixed schedule. e.g. School Year 2017, Semester 1. it is taught by a teacher and attended by students. since each item in the durable collections has an _id, now you can do the association in one go:

```
{
    subjectId: 'abc123',
    teacherId: 'def456',
    students: ['ghi789', 'xxx123', ... ],
    year: 2017,
    semester: 1,
    schedule: [
        {
            day: 'M',
            time: '1030'
        },
        {
            day: 'Th',
            time: '1500'
        }
    ]
}
```

does that make sense? this solves all the issues i mentioned above. it provides good flexibility and keeps an important distinction between a subject and that subject being offered to students at a scheduled time.

there's also the schedule there (handy), showing that the class meets 2x/week for that semester.

and now you can do your queries:

1. start with a teacher
2. grab their _id
3. search through the schoolClass collection with teacherId=_id, and also filtering by the school year and semester

you'll get back an array. each item in the array will give you the association to the subject (so you can show History 4 or Math 1 or whatever), and the list of students.

you can iterative over the students and, with their _id's, query the students collection to show their names. and with the schoolClass and student ids, now you can create an association for that student, in that class, for the uploaded documents.

you'll probably want another collection for those upload documents. each item might look like this:

```
{
    schoolClassId: 'zzz789',
    studentId: 'ghi789',
    documents: [] // however you want to handle that...
}
```

to borrow a term from relational databases, those id's (schoolClassId, studentId) are called foreign keys. they simply set up a reference back to an item in another collection.

it will be a fair amount of work to get everything correct and working, but i think it will provide you a lot of flexibility and solve your requirements.

Comment: Hi @zim, thank you so much for the response. In your opinion, what is the best way to go about assigning ids for students and classes? I have implemented the userId field to query based on teacher, but am struggling to figure out how to go about creating the student and class ids since all items will be generated by the user through forms.

Comment: @jdb94, as you've seen, mongo will create id's for the inserted items. sometimes i will use those id's as foreign keys. but if i'm creating "reference data", i will create a "name" field for that and use that for reference. in your case, i would treat the subjects as reference data, so Math 4 might have a "name" of MATH4, or European History Middle Ages might have a "name" of HISTORY_EURO_MID_AGES. (con't)

Comment: then, when you create a schoolClass, instead of a subjectId, you could have a "subjectName" and use MATH4 or whatever. it's easy to read, it's easy to search to find the reference, and it already exists when you need to reference it. for reference data like that, i will run some server code at startup to ensure the data is in the db (using upsert instead of insert). that helps w/ migration of reference data to other environments, and you don't have to worry about tracking id's. That said, that only works for reference data, and not stuff like students.